# JetBrains Fleet: Run Configuration for shell script

Tags: jetbrains-fleet

I'm trying to create a Fleet Run Configuration (v1.9) for my project in the `run.json` file, which should run a shell script with certain parameters. The problem is that the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/run-configs.html) only describes how to mark configuration as a command call, by setting `"type": "command"`, but does not tell exactly how to run the desired script. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few dozen minutes Fleet suggested that it is necessary to set another argument for the "command" configuration type - `"program"`, in the following format `"program": "./${your-script-file-name}.sh"`, in which case configuration will run successfully. It is worth noting, `program` flag in Fleet 1.9 documentation is omitted.

Comment: There is a reference about the `program` argument here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/execute-raw-commands.html